# Multiple API calls inside a Polymer Custom Element

Tags: polymer

I have put together a custom element using Polymer - `<x-flickr>` (http://tamas.io/x-flickr-custom-polymer-element/ || https://github.com/tamaspiros/x-flickr) - it essentially makes a REST call to the Flickr API and returns photos based on a search:

```
<polymer-jsonp id="ajax" auto url="http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key={{apikey}}&tags={{tag}}&per_page={{amount}}&page=1&format=json&jsoncallback="></polymer-jsonp>
```

This call returns some information about a particular photo but not everything. I'd like to reuse the unique ID returned via this call and make a second REST call to get further detail about the image. At the moment I display the photos via:

```
<template  id="photos" repeat="{{photo in photos}}">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://farm{{photo.farm}}.staticflickr.com/{{photo.server}}/{{photo.id}}_{{photo.secret}}.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
   </div>
 </template>
```

but I'd like to extend that so that I get the description of the photo as well (and this is the information that is not being returned by the first REST call displayed above) - so my template would look something like this:

```
    <template  id="photos" repeat="{{photo in photos}}">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://farm{{photo.farm}}.staticflickr.com/{{photo.server}}/{{photo.id}}_{{photo.secret}}.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
<p>{{photo.description}}</p> <!-- this should come from the 2nd API call -->
       </div>
     </template>
```

What's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked your project so you can see the details of what I'm about to describe here https://github.com/sjmiles/x-flickr.

The short answer to your question is to include a request element (`polymer-ajax`) inside the template repeat. That causes a request to spawn for each item in the repeat, and gives you easy access to the item data (the photo id in this case).

As I mentioned, you can see an example of how this can be done in the source here: https://github.com/sjmiles/x-flickr/blob/master/x-flickr.html#L46.

A few other notes:

- You don't need `JSONP` for these requests, simple Ajax calls will do, you can access the JSON directly. I used `polymer-ajax` instead of `polymer-jsonp`.
- You almost never need `addEventListener` in Polymer because you can listen to events using `on-<eventName>="methodName"` syntax directly in the HTML. In this case, you don't need to use events at all, because you can do the work with data binding.
- This could be done completely script-free, but I kept your script for setting `photos` property and sending the `x-flickr-load` event.

HTH

Comment: Scott - thank you. It's interesting to see that there are two rather different solutions to the same problem - one with scripting and one without. I honestly don't know which answer to accept - I love both. Thank you for the detailed explanation - it's really great to have this sort of support.

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle this: http://jsbin.com/yihovepi/1/edit (also includes some refactoring)

The `<p>{{photo.description}}</p>` is always in the template, but the `.description` is filled later by dynamically creating `<polymer-jsonp>` for each photo.

Note, I'm also using binding to the main polymer-jsonp element's `response` property:

```
<polymer-jsonp id="ajax" response="{{response}}">
```

This is super changed because the corresponding `responseChanged()` callback is called when that value is populated from the request.

Comment: Eric, the same praises go out to you as well - thank you for your prompt reply and I like your solution. In light of these two distinctive answers, which way is the best? The scripting or the non-scripting way?

Comment: Thanks. The Polymeric way, is the declarative way. Scott's post above captures that nicely. As with everything on the web platform, there are many ways to skin the cat. It's great we can show both.

Comment: Indeed. I'll have to accept one solution and I'll accept his - but don't take this the wrong way - I love your solution as well - it shows me nicely how to use scripts in Polymer. Keep up the good work guys!

Comment: Btw, a nice feature of the declarative method is that template repeats are _stable_. In other words, if you add/remove/modify records from `photos` the template will generate only the necessary changes in DOM, and will not re-request data for elements you already have.

Having said that, there are times when you may need to use JavaScript to do the extra work, so you are right that it's nice to have Eric's example of an imperative technique too.